# How to group records by day using timestamp as a field in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to group records by day for certain period. I have tried so far using this code added into the aggregate function:

```
 {
    $group : {
         _id : {  day: { $dayOfMonth: "$timestamp" }},
         count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
 }
```

And this is how a document looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("ec9cddd50e08a84cd3f4cccb"),
"orgid" : "5c48500d84430a3a4b828e85",
"timestamp" : ISODate("2019-03-28T14:00:00.000Z"),
"apiid" : {
    "zxczxczxczxczxc" : {
        "errortotal" : 6,
        "hits" : 6,
        "humanidentifier" : "Feedback",
        "identifier" : "663cfc345e42401c6443cfd635301f8f",
        "lasttime" : ISODate("2019-03-28T14:58:07.355Z"),
        "success" : 0,
        "totalrequesttime" : 0.0,
        "requesttime" : 0.0
    }
},
"apikeys" : {
    "00000000" : {
        "errortotal" : 3,
        "hits" : 3,
        "humanidentifier" : "",
        "identifier" : "00000000",
        "lasttime" : ISODate("2019-03-28T14:55:10.438Z"),
        "success" : 0,
        "totalrequesttime" : 0.0,
        "requesttime" : 0.0
    },
    "cae81afc" : {
        "errortotal" : 3,
        "hits" : 3,
        "humanidentifier" : "EE5RqcXMTqcWEx8nZv3vRATLspK2",
        "identifier" : "cbe81afc",
        "lasttime" : ISODate("2019-03-28T14:58:07.355Z"),
        "success" : 0,
        "totalrequesttime" : 0.0,
        "requesttime" : 0.0
    }
}
```

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Result I get is: [ { _id: { day: null }, count: 3 } ], it seems wrong for me since I have two documents with the same date and another document with different timestamp

UPDATE:
I also have this inside aggregate fuction:

```
  // Project things as a key/value array, along with the original doc
                {
                    $project: {
                        array: {$objectToArray: '$apikeys'},
                        doc: '$$ROOT',
                    }
                },

                // Match the docs with a field value of 'x'
                {$match: {'array.v.humanidentifier': {$in: trialCustomerUsers}}},
```

If I comment this part it will work fine the grouping, but the thing is I would also do some where statement in cases where I also dont know what woudl be the key, that's why I had to add this piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `$project`ed your all the root document in the `doc` field using `$$ROOT`. Now your aggregation should be as followed

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "array": { "$objectToArray": "$apikeys" },
    "doc": "$$ROOT"
  }},
  { "$match": { "array.v.humanidentifier": { "$in": trialCustomerUsers }}},
  { "$group" : {
    "_id" : { "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$doc.timestamp" }},
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just accumulate the records in a new field with the `$push` operator

```
{
    $group : {
         _id : {  day: { $dayOfMonth: "$timestamp" }},
         records: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
_id : {  day: { $dayOfMonth: "$timestamp" }}
```

to

```
_id : {  day: { $day: "$timestamp" } }
```

or you can do something like this

```
$group : {
   _id : null,
   day: '$timestamp',
   count: { $sum: 1 }
}
```

Comment: @Mizlul well are you encountering any errors? What is the result of the query?

Comment: Looks like something else I have in the aggregate function is causing  change the behaviour. Look I updated my question